# How can I switch between connections in MySQL CLI?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, azure-cli

I am following this tutorial [Create MySQL Server Database with Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/quickstart-create-mysql-server-database-using-azure-cli). I successfully created a connection; my problem is that when I use the mysql cli, I connect to the localhost connection, rather than the Azure connection. Is there a command that would let me choose which connection I want to work with in the cli?? Sorry if this is too obvios, but I couldn't get to a source that demonstrated how to do that. If this is a duplicate question, kindly express why and point me to a straightforward answer of the same issue and I will delete this one. Thanks!!

I tried the command "\connect azure-XXXX@mysql-azure-XXXX" but I get "->" like nothing happened, then typed "status" and still shows my localhost connection. Basically I have two active connections. When I turn off my localhost connection and try to check the status of my active "azure" connection, then I get the error " Lost connection to MySQL server during query"

`mysql> status`

```
86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Connection id:          10
Current database:
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Cipher in use is DHE-RSA-xxxxxxxx
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         8.0.17 MySQL Community Server - GPL
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             localhost via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    xxxx
Db     characterset:    xxxx
Client characterset:    xxx
Conn.  characterset:    xxx
TCP port:               3306
Uptime:                 18 hours 17 min 6 sec

Threads: 2  Questions: 11  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 115  Flush tables: 3  Open t
bles: 35  Queries per second avg: 0.000
```

this is what I am trying to get to:

```
Enter password: ***********
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 65512
Server version: 5.6.26.0 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> status
--------------
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.35, for Win64 (x86_64)

Connection id:          65512
Current database:
Current user:           myadmin@116.230.243.143
SSL:                    Not in use
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         5.6.26.0 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             mydemoserver.mysql.database.azure.com via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    gbk
Conn.  characterset:    gbk
TCP port:               3306
Uptime:                 2 days 9 hours 47 min 20 sec

Threads: 4  Questions: 34833  Slow queries: 2  Opens: 84  Flush tables: 4  Open tables: 1  Queries per second avg: 0.167
--------------

mysql>
```

Comment: You can just start another mysql session with `mysql -h mysql-azure-XXXX -u mysql-azure-XXXX`

Comment: @Barmar I tried that and this is what I get mysql> mysql -h mysql-azure-xxx.mysql.database.azure.com -u azure-xxx@mysq
l-azure-server1 -p
    -> status
    ->" I am not sure what I'm doing wrong according to the follow-through guide

Comment: You don't use `mysql` at the `mysql>` prompt, you do it at the regular shell prompt.

Comment: Either exit from this `mysql` command or open a new terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think you should quit or exit your MySQL:

```
mysql>quit
```

For more commands, please see [mysql Client Commands](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html).

Since you have followed the tutorial [Create MySQL Server Database with Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/quickstart-create-mysql-server-database-using-azure-cli).

Re-connect your Azure MySQL with command:

```
mysql --host <fully qualified server name> --user <server admin login name>@<server name> -p
```

For example：

```
mysql --host mydemoserver.mysql.database.azure.com --user myadmin@mydemoserver -p
```

After it's connected, the mysql utility displays a `mysql>` prompt at which you can type commands.

Following is example `mysql` output:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 65505
Server version: 5.6.26.0 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Then please run `mysql> status` again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Leon! I actually got it to work. I realized I had a different user name. I had to change the information straight from MySQL Workbench